# Understanding "犯人は保育園内で死亡！"

Tags: particles, context

From the first episode of *Death Note*, a TV news reporter says

> 犯人は保育園内で死亡！

I can see that する is being omitted from this sentence. But I'm curious/confused if other words or particles are also being omitted? In particular,

> 保育園内で

is a bit confusing. Here 内 appears to be modifying 保育園 as if it were a particle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

内 works as a suffix or as a standalone noun, similar to the English *inside* (e.g., inside a car/the inside of a car).

When used as a suffix, 内 is read ない (always, I think). As hiroki's answer suggests, it connotates the 'building'-ness of the preceding noun.

That is, 保育園[内]{ない}で sounds *in the building of the nursery* while 保育園(の中)で sounds broadly *in the nursery*.

Other examples of 内{ない}

- 時間[内]{ない}: within the time limit
- 期限[内]{ない}: before the expiration
- 校[内]{ない}: inside school building

When used as a noun, 内 is read うち. For example, 内{うち}と外.

Also note that when talking about *inside X(location)*, Xの内{うち} is not used. It should be Xの中. (For non-location, 計算の内{うち}=*expected* (lit. *within calculation*)).

Comment: When 内 is used as a suffix, do you know how it affects the pitch of the preceding word it modifies?

Comment: @George I think it does not change pitch, so the ending ない is HH or LL according as the preceding word is odaka or not. Not 100% sure though (I can't think of a good odaka word). [This](https://www.jp-lab.com/%E8%A4%87%E5%90%88%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%AA%AC%E6%98%8E) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this 内 of 保育園内 emphasize the location of the event. It's no problem  保育園で gramally but maybe 犯人 is not a student of 保育園 in this case, so appending 内 is better expression.